# Returning a local object results in garbage, while returning the same object temporary works fine

Tags: c++

I'm currently implementing my own string class (just for training), but I'm experiencing some problems in my substr() method:

```
MyString MyString::substr(size_t position, size_t length)
{
    if (checkBounds() || length == 0)
    {
        return MyString();
    }

    char* tmp = new char[length + 1];

    memcpy(tmp, this->s + position, length);

    tmp[length] = STRING_ESCAPE;

    MyString result(tmp);

    delete[] tmp;
    tmp = nullptr;

    return result;
}
```

When I call this method and print the return value (I'm printing the char array actuallay, not the object itself), I receive complete garbage, which is carried out as a bunch of squares.

But when I return a temporary object `return MyString(tmp)`, everything works fine. Initially i suspected this issue is associated to the delete[] operation, but commenting it out shows no effect.

The MyString constructor which is called is the following:

```
MyString::MyString(const char* s)
{
    size_t length = this->strlen(s);

    this->sLength = length;

    this->s = new char[length + 1];

    for (size_t i = 0; i <= length; ++i)
    {
        this->s[i] = *s;

        ++s;
    }
}
```

So where is my mistake? Thank you!

Comment: Is `STRING_ESCAPE` a fancy name for 0?

Comment: Why are you using `memcpy`? Use `strcpy`.

Comment: #define STRING_ESCAPE '\0'

Comment: It is hard to reconstruct what you actually do from the posted. Post a complete testable example.

Comment: You can find a testable exmaple here: http://pastebin.com/LiaF5Ztx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the two places you create MyString, they are being created within the context of your substr function.  The return statement has to make a copy of them.   Your copy constructor is probably not doing what you would need it to do.

A simpler design is for your substr function to return a pointer to a MyString that you create with operator new.

Comment: that's it! the standard copy constructor just copied the pointer. i implemented a custom copy constructor which deep-copys the string buffer, and now it's working fine. thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 0):

You were indeed missing the copy constructor. Something like this would do the work:

```c++
MyString::MyString(const MyString& other) {
  size_t length = strlen(other.s);     
  s = new char[length+1];
  strcpy(s,other.s);
  this->sLength = length;
}
```